# Математические операции с данными из текстового файла на Python

Tags: python

Есть задача с входными данными: [image]

Первая строка - количество рублей

Последующие 4 строки - список курсов евро

Необходимо найти самый оптимальный курс и вывести сколько евро по этому курсу можно купить.

Мой код на данный момент:

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    rubles = f.readlines()[0:1]
f.close()
rubles_st=rubles[0]
with open('in.txt') as d:
    vaules = d.readlines()[1:]
min_vaules = min(vaules)

print(min_vaules*rubles_st)
```

Я тут намудрил с типами данных и не могу умножить, получаю такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Помогите с решением.

Comment: @yolosora нет нет в задаче именно 4 курса

Comment: @yolosora оу да,спасибо нет вроде нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь перемножить строки. Их надо предварительно сконвертировать в нужный Вам тип данных. Решение:

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    rubles, *values = d.readlines()
min_value = min(map(float, values))

print(float(rubles) / min_value)
```

P.S. Используя менеджер контекста(`with`) файл закрывать вручную не требуется.

Comment: что означает *values ?

Comment: @Double Mid, в первую переменную(`rubles`) записывается первое значение массива(в данном случае - список строк, которые возвращает метод `.readlines()`), а в `*values` - все остальные значения. Так называемый pack/unpack итерируемых объектов.

Comment: хм,понятно а как код закидывает в переменную rubles именно первую строчку без среза?

Comment: @DoubleMid, он так делает именно из-за того, что "всё остальное" идет в `*values`. К примеру, добавим после `rubles` еще одну переменную. Туда будет записано 2 значение из списка, а в `*values` - два последних(вместо 3-х значений, как в ответе). Это что-то подобное такой записи: `rubles, kurs1, kurs2, kurs3, kurs4`, только в сокращенном варианте.

Comment: ладно спасибо понял

Comment: только там скорее всего делить все-таки нужно, а не умножать судя по примеру ожидаемых выходных данных))

Comment: @yolosora поправил, спасибо за комментарий :)

Comment: странно но код перестал работать ,выводит : 0.0025006399707441945

Comment: @DoubleMid скиньте данные, которые на вход отправили.

Comment: `27345
68.45
68.38
69
69.3 
`

Comment: те же самые из файла

Comment: аргументами местами надо поменять в делении :D

Comment: @floydya а понял надо местами делить и делимое поменять